# React Native - How to display FlatList immediately when moving to the other View in the ViewPagerAndroid?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-viewpager, android-sqlite, react-native-flatlist

I have the `ViewPagerAndroid` component in my application which has two `View` components.

**For Example:**

```
<ViewPagerAndroid>
   <View>// ... index 0 </View>
   <View>// ... index 1 </View>
</ViewPagerAndroid>
```

The initial view to load is the `0` index `View` component that contains the `FlatList` of words fetched from `SQLite` database. Now when I load my application the `FlatList` of words in the `0` index `View` component is loaded very fast when the component is mounted and I cannot feel the `FlatList` loading impression of the words list which is good.

When I select a specific word from the list, it moves me to the `1` index `View` component where I am also using the `FlatList` component which contains the very small list (maximum 8 to 12 items) of sentences fetched from `SQLite` database, that have the similar word that I selected in `0` index `View` component.

Now the problem is that when the word is selected from `0` index `View` component and when the `<ViewPagerAndroid>` moves me to `1` index `View` component the `FlatList` on the `1` index `View` component does not load immediately and loads after 1 or 2 seconds which is very bad impression. I can't use the `componentDidMount` or `componentWillMount` methods to load the `FlatList` on the `1` index `View` component before the component is loaded because both are in the same component inside the `<ViewPagerAndroid>`. Please can anyone tell what to do to load the `FlatList` on the `1` index `View` component immediately (same as the speed `FlatList` on the `0` index `View` component) without feeling the impression of loading the `FlatList` after 1 or 2 seconds?

I have optimized the `FlatList` on both `0` index `View` component and `1` index `View` component by following the guides of both first and second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47678959/react-native-flatlist-performance-problems-with-large-list). So, please don't say optimize your list and optimize your list and vice versa because I found that this is not the issue regarding optimization. Please, it is my humble request can any genius tell how to solve this issue because it is very very very important for me to solve? A little example will be more appreciated. Thanks !!!

Comment: Love you, trust me i was struggling with the same issue last month and failed to solve it because there is no such resource on the internet regarding this issue, so, i removed the `ViewPagerAndroid` component and put both the `View` components into separate components but this is what i don't want. I will still track this question to check may be someone solve this issue