# How to optimise Flatlist in react-native while rendering a long list with a large data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am rendering a list that has large data in its item, and when we scroll it speedily sometimes it is going blank and causing performance issues?

Is there anything like **react-virtualized** that we can use in react-native?

I want to add **refresh-CTA** button as well where I want to clear my list and scroll it to the top, the issue here is when clearing the list sometime one of my item is stuck on the top and not getting removed even if I am clearing the list data.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think blank screen momentarily is performance issue as FlatList content are rendered asynchronously offscreen which if scrolled fast than the fill rate, you will see see blank content. And this is mentioned in official docs as well https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist.html#example Under the hood implementation VirtualizedList can help you https://reactnative.dev/docs/virtualizedlist

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-Native FlatList performance problems with large list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47678959/react-native-flatlist-performance-problems-with-large-list)

Answer (score 0):

I could just copy `Filipe Merker` answer but that's not my way to do things, so here's some articles about it:

[flatlist-performance-tips](https://github.com/filipemerker/flatlist-performance-tips)

[8 ways to optimize React native FlatList performance](https://codingislove.com/optimize-react-native-flatlist-performance/)

[FlatList and VirtualizedList Scroll performance is laggy after 30+ rows](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13413)

[Optimizing Flatlist Configuration](https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration)

[react native 100+ items flatlist very slow performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44384773/react-native-100-items-flatlist-very-slow-performance)

[React-Native FlatList performance problems with large list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47678959/react-native-flatlist-performance-problems-with-large-list)